# Is this a known learning problem?

Tags: machine-learning, lg.learning, st.statistics, pac-learning

Let $(\mathcal{X},\rho)$ be a metric space (say, $\mathcal{X}=[0,1]$ with the Euclidean metric). Let $\alpha:\mathcal{X}\to[0,1]$ be unknown. Suppose that $\mathcal{X}$ is endowed with a distribution $\mu$ from which $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ is sampled iid. Further, for each $X_i$, we observe $Y_i\sim\mathrm{Bernoulli}(\alpha(X_i))$.

Our goal is to recover $\alpha$ from the finite sample, under some loss function (I tend to favor the pointwise loss $\ell(\hat\alpha,\alpha)=$
$$KL(\hat\alpha||\alpha)
=
\hat\alpha\log(\hat\alpha/\alpha)
+
(1-\hat\alpha)\log[(1-\hat\alpha)/(1-\alpha)]
,$$
but other loss functions can be considered also.)

Obviously, there is no hope of recovering $\alpha$ without some regularity condition, such as Lipschitz continuity.

Does this problem fall under some known framework?

Edit: Following Clement's comment, a clarification. The loss I defined above is *pointwise*, at each $x$ --- so it should really be $\ell(\hat\alpha(x),\alpha(x))$. The overall risk is then 
$$R(\alpha)=E_X[\ell(\hat\alpha(X),\alpha(X))].$$

Comment: Based on your description, $\alpha$ is a function to be learnt, but your suggested loss seems to treat it as a single parameter in $[0,1]$?

Comment: My loss is pointwise, at each $x$; I updated the question.

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification!

Comment: I'm really just looking for related keywords. So far "passive Lipschitz bandits" comes to mind -- anything else?

Comment: To be clear, we are given the list of pairs $\{(X_i,Y_i)\}$?

Comment: By the way, the triple $(X,\rho,\mu)$ is called a metric measure space.

Comment: @LiorSilberman (1) yes, you get to observe $(X_i,Y_i)$ for $i=1,\ldots, n$. (2) yes, I know

Comment: We investigated a version of this setup in [1], but not from this PAC perspective. Didn't come across any relevant PAC literature. The issue we were looking at is that loss functions such as yours are not necessarily "identifiable" from samples $(x_i,y_i)$. Happy to explain more. [1] https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.09680

Comment: @usul Sure, would be happy to discuss this! I'd send you an email but your identity is non-obvious, so feel free to shoot me one. https://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/~karyeh/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, we wrote a paper on it, so now it's definitely known:
https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.09886